# MFC: Don't want to highlight full row when click the first column in a CListCtrl

Tags: mfc, highlight, clistctrl

I have a report-styled CListCtrl WITHOUT LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT in my dialog, and when I click on the first column it highlight the full row.
I don't want this, how could I disable this behavior?

Comment: Does it highlight the full *column* or *row* ? I'm confused.

Comment: Sorry, it highlight the full row, not column.

Comment: Somehow, LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT must be set. Did you check the listview styles with Spy++ ?

Comment: Thanks for the advise, but if LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT was setted, it should highlight the full row no matter what column was clicked. And I think this is a default action of report-sytled CListCtrl because it works the same in a new project.